# Interpretation of GDB output

Tags: c++, gdb

I haven't used GDB much. Usually I examine simple variables but never classes. This time I'm examining classes as I'm starting on a new project (LLVM).

Here is the output of

`disp CachedTable`

`CachedTable = {<llvm::DenseMapBase<llvm::DenseMap<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int, llvm::DenseMapInfo<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > >, std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int, llvm::DenseMapInfo<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > >> = {<No data fields>}, Buckets = 0x1a9e190, NumEntries = 2, NumTombstones = 0, NumBuckets = 64}`

How do I interpret this output?

Any help  is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is output of data members of `llvm::DenseMap` class.
(http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/DenseMap_8h_source.html)

The first part of output means that it's base class `llvm::DenseMapBase` has no data members:

```
<llvm::DenseMapBase<llvm::DenseMap<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int, llvm::DenseMapInfo<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > >, std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int, llvm::DenseMapInfo<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > >> = {<No data fields>}
```

The rest output prints `llvm::DenseMap` data members values:

```
Buckets = 0x1a9e190, NumEntries = 2, NumTombstones = 0, NumBuckets = 64
```

---

Usually it's hard to interpret one line outputs like this, especially for long structs/classes from unknown code, so it's worth to turn on gdb's pretty printing mode:

```
(gdb) set print pretty on
```

See [Print Settings](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html):

```
set print pretty on
    Cause gdb to print structures in an indented format with one member per line, like this:

              $1 = {
                next = 0x0,
                flags = {
                  sweet = 1,
                  sour = 1
                },
                meat = 0x54 "Pork"
              }
```

Comment: What are the comma separated items? Are they inherited classes?

Comment: No, they are data members. The 1-st is a pointer and 3 others are numeric values. (It is implementation of a hash table)

Comment: I should clarify. This is what I meant by comma separated items, `<llvm::DenseMapBase<llvm::DenseMap<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int, llvm::DenseMapInfo<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > >, std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int, llvm::DenseMapInfo<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > >>`. Are these data members?

Comment: No, they are data types. They are template parameters for different templates used to construct `llvm::DenseMapBase` class. Some of them are template parameters to another template parameters. `llvm::DenseMapBase` is highly templated class.

Comment: Oh I see. Greatly appreciate you help.